# Android webview fixed background

Tags: android, css, webview

I struggled so much to have a fixed background inside the webview.

First I tried this using CSS, But I found out background-attachment:fixed doesn't work in android, at least till 4 (don't know about newer versions).

The other option was to have a scrollable DIV which android doesn't support either.

I didn't try iscroll for this problem, but earlier used it somewhere else and wasn't satisfied. I don't know if it's possible with an iframe.

The other option was to set the background using android. I read much about this and tried many thing, one for example was using a container layout with a background and setting webview background to transparent.

It worked in 2.2 with a delay, in 4 it didn't work at all.

I'm so tired wasting a lot of time to achieve this small thing.

Do you have any other idea to implement this?

Comment: WebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
WebView.setBackgroundResource(color.TRANSPARENT);  did you tried this ?

Comment: Yes, and I mentioned this. It doesn't work in 4.0

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3301 It says they added support for this in jelly bean 4.1...

Comment: @Παύλος my target is 2.2 to 4.0 where most users reside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

This is how you do it:

First make your project base on 11, but in AndroidManifest set minSdkVersion to 8

```
wv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) wv.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

this.wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        wv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) wv.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
});
```

For safety put this in your style:

```
BODY, HTML {background: transparent}
```

worked for me on 2.2 and 4